# Arduino takes 1-2 seconds to process serial input, how can I speed this up?

Tags: python, arduino

I am almost entirely new to arduino/C++ so forgive me if this seems stupid. I am using a python program that detects faces in the camera frame and sends the x and y coordinate of the face to the arduino via serial (I have not implemented any code to deal with y yet). This works so long as I limit how often it sends the coordinates, however if they are sent too fast, the arduino seems to simply stop responding. My hypothesis as to why is that it is not able to read the data fast enough and it is lost before it can be processed. I know ultimately 1-2 seconds is not that big of a deal but unfortunately for me I'm a bit of a perfectionist and a 1-2 second delay really gets on my nerves.

As for the python script:

```
while True:
    
    # Facial recognition stuff here

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        print(x, y)
        if i == 30:
            coord = f'{x} {y}'
            arduinoData.write(coord.encode())
            i = 0
    i += 1
```

and the code running on my arduino:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;
int gLED = 2;
int rLED = 3;
String words[2];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(rLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(gLED, OUTPUT);
  myservo.attach(8);
  myservo.writeMicroseconds(1450);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String input = Serial.readStringUntil('\r');
    int spaceIndex = input.indexOf(' ');
    if (spaceIndex != -1) {
      words[0] = input.substring(0, spaceIndex);
      words[1] = input.substring(spaceIndex + 1);
    } else {
      words[0] = input;
      words[1] = "";
    }

    int pos1 = words[0].toInt();
    if (pos1 > 300) {
      digitalWrite(gLED, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(rLED, LOW);
      myservo.writeMicroseconds(1400);
    }
    if (pos1 < 240) {
      digitalWrite(rLED, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(gLED, LOW);
      myservo.writeMicroseconds(1510);
    }
    if (pos1 >= 240 && pos1 <= 300) {
      digitalWrite(gLED, LOW);
      digitalWrite(rLED, LOW);
      myservo.writeMicroseconds(1450);
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any tips on how I can speed up the response? Is it slow because of something stupid that I'm doing or is there maybe a different protocol that is faster? I briefly looked into i2c but I'm not sure if it's a better option.

Comment: You're using readString which is very slow. User Serial.read() to get one character at a time and add those characters to a String. You can use Serial.find to look for a certain character in the buffer

Comment: readStringUntil('\r') also needs some '\r' characted in the stream, otherwise it'll wait until the timeout occurs (it's about 1 second if I recall it correctly)

Answer (score 2):

@Roman is true. May be better to monitor the serial at regular interval and get data as they arrive:

```
unsigned long timer;

void loop() {
  if (millis() - timer > 200) { //tick every 200mS
    timer=millis();
    String input = serialListen();
    // etc.....
  }
}


String serialListen() {
  String SerMsg = "";
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    if (inChar == '\n') {  //end char
      return SerMsg;
    } else {
      // add it to the inputString:
      SerMsg += inChar;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I switched to Serial.read() and it is much much faster, I used example 2 from this* thread as a reference for anyone wondering

* https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serial-input-basics-updated/382007